# UNION vs. JOIN, b and c not defined? (sqlite3)

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
select city, prov, a, b, c from ( 
select count(city) as a, city, prov from locations left outer join rides on src=lcode 
group by city 
union 
select count(city) as b, city, prov from locations left outer join rides on dst=lcode 
group by city 
union
select count(city) as c, city, prov from locations l left outer join enroute e on l.lcode=e.lcode 
group by city 
) group by city;
```

So I got an error saying "no such column: b" (and also column c). Is it possible to solve this without changing a lot of this query?

Comment: When you perform unions, note that all of the select statements in those unions must have the same column names.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is returning three columns, `a`, `city`, and `prov`. That is, for a `union`/`union all` query, the column names come from the first subquery.  There is no `b` or `c`.

Presumably, you want some sort of `JOIN`, not `UNION ALL`.  However, your question does not explain what you are trying to do.  And it doesn't have sample data or desired results.  So, it is really hard to say what you actually want.

It strikes me that you actually want:

```
select city, prov, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)
from ((select city, prov, count(city) as a, null as b, null as c
       from locations left outer join
            rides on src = lcode 
       group by city 
      ) union all
      (select city, prov, null, count(city), 0
       from locations left outer join
            rides
            on dst = lcode 
       group by city 
      ) union all
      (select city, prov, null, null, count(city) 
       from locations l left outer join
            enroute e
            on l.lcode = e.lcode 
       group by city 
      )
     ) abc
group by city;
```

Answer (score -1):

The expressions that are not encapsulated within an aggregate function and must be included in the GROUP BY clause. For Unions, all of the select statements in those unions must have the same column names.
Below would do the required tasks.

```
select * from ( 
select count(city) as cityCount, prov from locations left outer join rides on src=lcode 
group by prov
union 
select count(city) as cityCount, prov from locations left outer join rides on dst=lcode 
group by prov
union
select count(city) as cityCount,prov from locations l left outer join enroute e on l.lcode=e.lcode 
group by prov
);
```

Doesn't require an additional groupby for Outside subquery. It will already be grouped by provinces of locations.